# Setting Reporting Parameter Values

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report parameters that look like below image:

[image]

Now, user wants that when for example, Taxed parameter is set to True, other similar parameter with a BIT data type should automatically become False, in other word, only one parameter can be set to true at the same time as in the image below:

[image]

How do I achieve this in SSRS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to - not how you're describing.  You could do cascading parameters, but those can only flow in one direction.  Why not just use a single-select dropdown list with the options Valued, Taxed, & Rated?